# reasoning about probabilities and indistinguishability

Tags: z3, smt

I'm looking for hints on formal reasoning capturing notion of indistinguishability, that is, the same probability distribution of a random variable. Such a variable could be sampled from 0/1 space while considering XOR games with random bits, or it could be sampled from a large ring. The latter case would be equipped with modular addition.

At best, any known way to conclude that distribution of the sum with a random variable with flat distribution is flat?
Alternatively, what kind of reasoning about probabilities is doable with Z3?

The best match that I came across is probably reasoning about Bayesian Belief Networks (Michael Huth etal at Esorics), still feeling lost. So, where to start from? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really answer the question, but it may be of interest that we recently designed a (very specialized) model checker for (some) probabilistic systems based on Z3. There's a [paper](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-10696-0_30) about it and an [implementation](https://github.com/wintersteiger/ProbabilisticZ3-src). In our very special setting everything is discretized, so it may be possible to answer questions of  'flatness' or similar, but it would probably still be very expensive.

Comment: Thank you Christoph, let me check it.